# Is it possible to roll back from VS2013 Ultimate to a previously installed VS2013 Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to roll back from VS2013 Ultimate Trial to a previously installed VS2013 Professional?

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69936289-676f-4503-ba3a-2eebc32dd3b6/downgrading-from-vs-2010-ultimate-to-premium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried uninstalling the Ultimate trial and then just ran VS2015 professional and it worked fine, so far.